# How to know which port is busy or free on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see all active connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/11207/how-can-i-see-all-active-connections)

I have some conflict of ports and my WampServer didn't work, so I have to know which port is used.

Is there a command line command ? or any program to monitor the ports ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To list open ports and listening services, then from within command prompt, type

```
netstat -a
```

or

```
netstat -an
```

For more details, in command prompt type

```
netstat ?
```

Answer (score 4):

Telnet attempts to connect to a server on a port

```
telnet <hostname> <port>
```

You will either connect, or not.

Simple tried and true method.

Works on Windows or Linux

Answer (score 3):

To get the most information about what ports are open, what state they're in, and other relevant network information, I would suggest you download [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html#Windows). It's a free network mapper/port scanner, and by typing either `nmap -v 127.0.0.1` in Command Prompt or `127.0.0.1` in the "Host" or "Target" field in the GUI counterpart (called Zenmap), you will quickly obtain any information you need about open ports on your computer.